# Different Words in Russian, Same Meaning in English!

Tags: перевод, словоупотребление, значения, выбор-слова

I practice Russian in [Duolingo](https://www.duolingo.com) app and there are a lot of words that have **same meaning in English**. For example:

- мои - мой - моя - мое
- это - этот - эта
- как - что

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to start learning grammar 
In Russian, we have 3 genders(masculine, feminine and neutral) 
For example:
Masculine: **мой брат** --> my brother
Feminine: **моя сестра** --> my sister
Neutral: **моё такси** -->  my taxi
Plural: **мои деньги** --> my money
Good luck

Comment: Thank you so much 

Comment: @Farid You're welcome